Why we are not able to run the scripts consistently?
Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: socket hang up
The script should work consistently when we run the script for multiple times

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
